# How would I fix the reviews endpoint of my code to update the reviews of a book in my database?

Tags: node.js, express, postman, backend

I am currently doing an IBM course on backend development using Express and NodeJS. One of the final tasks for my project is to register as a user, login successfully, create a JWT token after successfully logging in, and finally leaving a review of a book based off its ISBN after successfully logging in. I used postman for testing, and everything works up till the review step. I get the logged in message and a JWT token, which I then promptly place in the headers section on postman. I changed the endpoint to the required one and use a put request. Despite this I still get the "User not logged in message." Any help regarding this would be appreciated!

```js
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
let books = require("./booksdb.js");
const regd_users = express.Router();

let users = [];

const isValid = (username) => {
  // Check if the username exists in the users array
  return users.some((user) => user.username === username);
};

const authenticateUser = (username, password) => {
  // Check if the username and password match the records
  return users.some((user) => user.username === username && user.password === password);
};

// Only registered users can login
regd_users.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  // Check if the username and password are provided
  if (!username || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "Username and password are required" });
  }

  // Check if the username and password match
  if (authenticateUser(username, password)) {
    // Generate a JWT token
    const token = jwt.sign({ username }, "access");

    // Set req.user with the authenticated username
    req.user = { username };

    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Login successful", token });
  }

  return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid username or password" });
});

// Add a book review
regd_users.put("/auth/review/:isbn", (req, res) => {
  const isbn = req.params.isbn;
  const review = req.body.review;
  const username = req.user.username; // The username is stored in the req.user object

  // Check if the book exists in the database
  if (books.hasOwnProperty(isbn)) {
    const book = books[isbn];

    // Check if the user already has a review for the book
    if (book.reviews.hasOwnProperty(username)) {
      // Modify the existing review
      book.reviews[username].review = review;
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "Review modified successfully" });
    } else {
      // Add a new review for the user
      book.reviews[username] = {
        username: username,
        review: review,
      };
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "Review added successfully" });
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: "Book not found" });
  }
});

module.exports.authenticated = regd_users;
module.exports.isValid = isValid;
module.exports.users = users;
```

Comment: The exception `User not logged in message` is not present in the code you provided, it's is another file i assume? One problem i see is that when you assign user in the request inside the login route, it will assign only for that request. It will not be available when another request comes in. So inside the review route the user is always gonna be null

Comment: Yes, that seemed to be the problem, I ended up modifying the code and fixing it. Thank you!